Getting build errors while converting the MAUI project from .NET 6 to .NET 8
I am in the process of converting the MAUI project to latest .NET 8 version.
For this I used upgrade assistant tool provided by .NET framework and Microsoft.
Eventually after this completion, when i try to clean and rebuild the project, I am getting the following error:
APT2067 -  failed processing manifest
APT2260 -  resource mipmap/edupay (aka com.orovia.Edupay:mipmap/edupay) not found.
           This error is likely caused by an issue with the android manifest file or an Android manifest generation attribute in a source code file

MSB3030 -  Could not copy the file "C:\Nuget\xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources  
           \grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\ext\upb-generated\envoy\config\filter\network\http_connection_manager\v2\http_connection_manager.upb.h" because it was not found.

MSB3021 -  Unable to copy file "C:\Nuget\xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h" 
           to "bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h". 
           Could not find a part of the path 'bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\grpclb\client_load_reporting_filter.h'.

          
MSB3027 -  Could not copy "C:\Nuget\xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\tsi\alts\zero_copy_frame_protector\alts_grpc_privacy_integrity_record_protocol.h" 
           to "bin\Debug\net8.0-ios\iossimulator-x64\Firebase.CloudFirestore.resources\grpc.xcframework\ios-arm64\grpc.framework\PrivateHeaders\src\core\tsi\alts\zero_copy_frame_protector\alts_grpc_privacy_integrity_record_protocol.h". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

Not able to figure out what is causing this issue and how to resolve the same.
Any help would be much appreciated.
Tried cleaning, deleting bin and obj folders, and then rebuilding the project,
The issue still exists.

Please do not post error messages as images and read how to ask.

@Julian certainly I ll adhere to guidelines the next time I post any question and thanks for suggestion.

Please edit your current question, because this will make it easier for others with a similar issue to find your question and potential answers.

It’s a good idea to include code, errors and structures as text, not links and images. Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at No Images Please

@Julian I have editted my question by removing the image of actual build error and just posted few error lines from that as text.

The problem might be the iOS Firebase nuget package as explained in this post
This only happens on dotnet 8 on windows platform. One way of fixing this would be to only build the app for android when run on windows by removing the ios framework from your csproj and instead adding something like:
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))=='false'"> $(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-ios</TargetFrameworks>


Thanks for the suggestion. I tried out the above solution, but still I get the following error : [![Build Error][1]][1][1]: https://i.sstatic.net/yv9xp0w0.png . Any suggestions on how to fix this error?..And Is there no alternative way that I can run my MAUI project without any errors keeping IOS target platform in windows machine?

If you want to add image to your project, you need to add the image file to the Resources\AppIcon folder and then set the property to MauiImage. it is not necessary to change the code in the AndroidManifest.xml file. You can refer to Add an app icon to a .NET MAUI app project.
The second issue is about Xamarin.firebase.ios.cloudfirestore NuGet in MAUI, it is not supported with .net8-iOS. You have to find other packages or make a binding library.
